CorePlot in Microsoft NET8-iOS
I'm migrating a Xamarin.iOS app to Microsoft net8.0-ios as Xamarin is deprecated. I use a nuget for CorePlot charting that has a reference to xamarin.ios so it's unusable in the newer project migrated away from Xamarin.iOS. Does anyone know how to bind or reference CorePlot into a net8.0-ios project? Anyone willing to create a nuget for it?
https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CorePlot

It has been over 4 years since the last release - I’d assume this is a dead project

It doesn't matter if CorePlot is dead or not, it works and works great. I just need to get it to work in the newer net8-ios by Microsoft after Xamarin.iOS is deprecated so we can continue our implementation in our app. @jason
